# When there are nested loops, how should I decide which loop should be nested?

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I came across some code that have nested loops : there is a list of measurement file, containing a list of measurements. Each measurements must be compared to a list of reference measurements to do some checks.

Here is a quick example.

```cpp
class Measurement {
public:
    bool operator==(const Measurement& other) { return isEqual(other); }

private:
    bool isEqual(const Measurement& other) const;

    /* some private fields */
};

class MeasurementFile
{
public:
    std::vector<Measurement> measurements;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Measurement> referenceMeasurements = createReferenceMeasurements();
    std::vector<MeasurementFile> files = createMeasurementFiles();

    for (auto & singleFile : files) {
         for (auto & singleMeasurement : singleFile.measurements) {
              for (auto & reference : referenceMeasurements) {
                   if (reference == singleMeasurement) {
                        doSomething(singleMeasurement);
                   }
              }
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main could also be written this way :

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Measurement> referenceMeasurements = createReferenceMeasurements();
    std::vector<MeasurementFile> files = createMeasurementFiles();

    for (auto & reference: referenceMeasurements) {
         for (auto & singleFile : files) {
              for (auto & singleMeasurement : singleFile.measurements) {
                   if (reference == singleMeasurement) {
                        doSomething(singleMeasurement);
                   }
              }
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is : between the two above solutions, which is the best one (if any)? Is it only a matter of preference?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `auto &` in your loops. Typically loop order is based on frequency and order of access. You're correct that it could be written either way, but realistically the first option would be better, and you would be doing less loading from memory, and have better cache reuse.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should try to make your code as readable as possible. For example, if you have to loop through every student in each year for a school, it would make more sense to loop through the years first and nest the students loop inside them. In your example, both loops can be seen as equivalent even for this, so I think you are good to go either way.

Comment: @ChrisMM You're right, I have changed `auto` to `auto &`. Good point about memory loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically loop order is based on frequency and order of access. You're correct that it could be written either way, but realistically the first option would be better, and you would be doing less loading from memory, and have better cache reuse.

The use of `auto &` will explicitly tell the compiler not to make copies (your original did not have the `&`; without it you would be recreating the `singleFile` object many times over, without need. The first option significantly reduces this. That being said, the first option would still be better for reuse, by reusing the `singleFile` as much as possible.